# Declare generic type globally

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to declare ts type globally. I have sth like this `type Nullable<T> = T | null` which is used in project files. I dont want to copy this part in each file. I tried to declare this type in `declarations.ts` or `declarations.d.ts` like this `declare type Nullable<T> = T | null`, my IDE and compiler is OK with this but when I use this project as a module (import) in another project, then I get an error: `Cannot find name 'Nullable'` in d.ts files.

Can you help me how can I declare this generic type globally? Do you have any ideas? Thank you for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the type in global to make the type globally accessible without any import.

```
declare global {
    type Nullable<T> = T | null
}
```

**Note** As with anything in a global namespace you will run the risk of name conflicts with other modules.

Comment: ahh, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you could use exports:

```js
// lib.ts
export type Nullable<T> = T | null;

// main.ts
import { Nullable } from "./lib.ts";

let a: Nullable = null;
```

Of course you'd still have to add an import statement at the top of every file.